# Is there any way to "reset" 'id' column indexes in EF Core with Identity?

Tags: database, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am using ASP.NET Core Identity for my uni project, but to match the project's requirements  I changed primary key type to int. Everything works fine, each new record has last added record's `Id` incremented by 1.

While testing many features I had been deleting some records. When I want to add some data, either by `Register` class or `SeedData` new records continue to appear in database with `Id` of last added record incremented by 1 (even though no records exist in the table), like [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLHyf.png).

Just for some "visual clarity" I'd like these records `Ids` to start counting from 1, especially in my [`Roles` table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQDEW.png), where I have three roles: `admin`, `moderator`, `user`, so it would be nice to set their `Ids` to 1, 2 and 3, respecitvely.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SQL Server, you can use the following SQL statement to reset the identity seed:

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('Roles', RESEED, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, the auto incremeant of `id` is generated by the sql server and has nothing to do with EF Core. you can only say to EF core the `type` is `int` and is auto incremented. so the Auto Increment will happen in sql server side and not from EF Core. so you have to reset the `Id` in the sql server level with this

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('[TestTable]', RESEED, 0);
GO
```

As you can see below the image from migration file created by ef core, it says

```
Id = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
```

the `"SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"` here means minimum value to start from is 1 and increment by 1. you cannot reset the id to start from 1 again using EF Core

[image]